# Set a variable number of bits in a signal

Tags: verilog

I have a module with input, output such as:

```
input [2:0] start;
input [2:0] range;
input [4:0] sig_in; 
output [4:0] sig_out;
```

I want to set some bits of signal `sig_in`.  For example, 2 bits from bit 2 to bit 4.  How can do it in Verilog?  We can't use "not a constant value" in a `for` loop.

Let me give an example:

```
initial 
sig_in = 5'b00000;
start = 3'b2;
range = 3'b2;
```

Expected output:

```
sig_out = 5'b01100;
```

Using `generate` and `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without any loop at all:

```
  always_comb 
    sig_out = ((5'b1 << range) - 1'b1) << start;
```

`(5'b1 << range) - 1` creates a mask for the 'range bits', i.e. 00011 for two bits.
you only need to shift it left by 'start' bits.

This relates it to signal_in as in your example:

```
  always_comb 
    sig_out = (((5'b1 << range) - 1'b1) << start) | signal_in;
```

Comment: That's a good idea, it's worked. But it need to be related to input `sig_in`. Anyway, it's very helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: IN this case it would look like ` sig_out = (((5'b1 << range) - 1'b1) << start) | sig_in;`. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `generate` construct.  Use a `for` loop to loop through all the bits of the output and set any bits that are inside the desired range.

```
module dut (
    input [2:0] start,
    input [2:0] range,
    input [4:0] sig_in,
    output reg [4:0] sig_out
);

integer i;
always @* begin
    sig_out = sig_in;
    for (i=0; i<5; i=i+1) begin
        if ((i >= start) && (i < (start+range))) begin
           sig_out[i] = 1; 
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```